# Refreshing a Firebase object manually in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a small app where a user can input a persons name and add them to a board and then users can up or down vote them (for fantasy football). Currently, the only thing that happens immediately without need for refreshing the page is when a player is added via the text input box. This does a little fade-in for the object and it comes right to the screen:

```
addPlayer(player) {

this.state.user ?
  this.database.push().set({ playerContent: player, votes: 0})
  :
  console.log("Not Logged In")
}
```

Is this done in real time because it is a push? How could I have the board of players update after a user casts a vote? Right now, when say Jane Doe has two votes, and John Doe has 2 votes and you vote John Doe up to 3, he doesn't jump up ahead of Jane Doe until after you refresh the page. Is there a way to refresh each individual object as you cast a vote? Here's my voting code

```
upvotePlayer(playerId) {
if(this.state.user) {
  let ref = firebase.database().ref('/players/' + playerId + '/voters');

  ref.once('value', snap => {
    var value = snap.val()
    if (value !== null) {            
        ref.child(this.uid).once('value', snap => {
          if (snap.val() === 0 || snap.val() === -1 || snap.val() == null){
            ref.child(this.uid).set(1);
          } else if (snap.val() === 1) {
          ref.child(this.uid).set(0);
          }
          else {
            console.log("Error in upvoting. snap.val(): " + snap.val())
          }

        })

    } else {
        console.log("Doesn't exist")
        ref.child(this.uid).set(1);
    }
});
}
else {
    console.log("Must be logged in to vote.")
}
}
```

If I'm missing relevant code please let me know and I'll supply it. I tried calling `componentDidMount` after the vote is cast and `this.forceUpdate()` (even if it is discouraged) just to see if it was a solution, which it didn't seem to be.

Heres the player component which is rendered in App.js

```
{
  orderedPlayersUp.map((player) => {
    return (
      <Player
        playerContent={player.playerContent}
        playerId={player.id}
        key={player.id}
        upvotePlayer={this.upvotePlayer}
        downvotePlayer={this.downvotePlayer}
        userLogIn={this.userLogIn}
        userLogOut={this.userLogOut}
        uid={this.uid}
      />
    )
  })
}
```

---

## Edit

When I change the upvotePlayer function's database call to `.on` rather than `.once` and proceed to upvote a player, it spews out an infinite amount of my console.logs from this componentWillMount function:

App.js line 51 is the console.log below.

```
  this.database.on('child_changed', function (snapshot) {
    var name = snapshot.val();
    console.log("Player: " + name.playerContent + " has  " + name.votes + " votes.")
  })
```

After 20 seconds or so when it overloads itself, an error page comes up and says `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Changing the componentWillMount functions database call to `this.database.once` instead of `.on` cuts down on the infinite loop, but still throws `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

The error:
[image]
[image]

A gist with the App.js (where the voting occurs (upvotePlayer)) and Player.jsx. [Gist with App.js and Player.jsx](https://gist.github.com/scottmiller2/c1e5beb878db553ede50b79ff5fa70cf)

---

## Edit2

Votes started registering immediately to the screen when I changed from `.once` to `.on` in the Player.jsx file in the comondentDidMount() as seen below. To clarify, this solves my issue of the voting icons not changing in real-time when I change from upvote to downvote. I have yet to test whether or not it registers one player overtaking another with more votes as I originally asked. Just wanted to clarify for anyone who may look through this code to help themselves.

```
componentDidMount() {
  let ref = firebase.database().ref('/players/' + this.playerId + '/voters');

  ref.on('value', snap => {
    var value = snap.val()

    if (value !== null && this.props.uid !== null) {       
        ref.child(this.props.uid).on('value', snap => {
          if (snap.val() === 1){
            this.setState({ votedUp: true, votedDown: false })
            }
          else if (snap.val() === 0) {
            this.setState({ votedUp: false, votedDown: false })
          }
          else if (snap.val() === -1) {
            this.setState({ votedDown: true, votedUp: false })
          }
          else {
          console.log("Error calculating the vote.")
          }
        })
    } else {
      //Error
    }
});

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your firebase call is a .once() call at the moment. That will only call the database once. If you want your component to continue to listen for changes then you need to switch to a .on() call. So that would be `ref.child(this.uid).on(...)` instead of `ref.child(this.uid).once(...)`

```
ref.child(this.uid).on('value', snap => {
          if (snap.val() === 0 || snap.val() === -1 || snap.val() == null){
            ref.child(this.uid).set(1);
          } else if (snap.val() === 1) {
          ref.child(this.uid).set(0);
          }
          else {
            console.log("Error in upvoting. snap.val(): " + snap.val())
          }

        })
```

Comment: I see — thanks for the clarification. That is precisely what I need it to do and that makes sense after looking at the documentation you posted in the other thread. However, when I change to `.on` inside the upvote function I seem to be getting an infinite loop type error. I updated my original post with an edit. Thanks again for the information

Comment: can you give me more details about the error. What does it say?

Comment: If the error is happening with .once() aswell then this error is unconnected to this question. that said, if you remove the up and downvote onClick handlers on the player component does the stack stop overflowing?

Comment: I figured it out and added the changed code to the bottom of the original post. As you said, I needed to change from `.once` to `.on`, but I did it inside of the 'Player.jsx componentDidMount() function' and it seemed to have made the votes register to the screen immediately. Thanks again for the help Josh